# Weird message on dvi mode

Tags: miktex, dvi, ghostscript

I am getting the following message when I visualize in dvi mode:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Some PostScript specials could not be rendered.
Data: Error: /undefined in H.S
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   PermitFileReading   --nostringval--   PermitFileWriting   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1914   1   3   %oparray_pop   1913   1   3   %oparray_pop   1897   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:95/300(L)--   --dict:17/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript  9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Dvi\Ghostscript.cpp
Line: 372
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 8 Business Edition, 64-bit (build 9200)
Invokers: explorer/TeXnicCenter
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\acb\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\acb\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
UserInstall: C:\Users\acb\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\acb\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\acb\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

What does it mean?

Comment: That message is not produced by your `dvi` viewer, but by `ghostscript` which is invoked from the `dvi` viewer, presumably because your `dvi` contains PostScript specials. Try to convert your `dvi` using `dvips` and look at the result with `ghostview`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3):

For me the following usually works:

In YAP, the DVI viewer, in menu `View` go to `Render method` and select `dvips`. This way the PostScript specials in the DVI will be correctly interpreted.

Comment: It doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 2):

Not everything that you might want to do in print (or can do with some particular target format) can be expressed directly in TeX' own DVI language, so there is a \special mechanism to pass commands directly to the backend. Some of the drivers make heroic efforts to emulate the others, but (as you see) not always with success.

In this case, it looks like you used some command that should only be used for pdflatex. Have you tried pdflatex directly, not latex --> DVI --> PDF?

Comment: I guess your last sentence should read like “Try out the direct production of PDF, i.e. call the profile LaTeX --> PDF.”

Comment: @Speravir, yes, that was the intent.